# Prevent additional windows from displaying in powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

The idea here is to uninstall a program silently.  Unfortunately the program's msi is custom and executes a batch file during the uninstall process.  What I am trying to do is prevent this window from displaying during the powershell uninstall script.  I'm using wmi uninstall method because the msi that the program uses doesn't respond to quite or uninstall flags (/q, /x, /uninstall).  I have attempted to run it as a background job but the window still appears.  The script looks as follows:

```
start-job -scriptblock `
    {(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Product |? {$_Name -eq "Annoying1"}).uninstall()} `
    -Name Uninstall1
$job = get-job -name Uninstall1
wait-job $job
receive-job $job
```

This will run mostly hidden until the uninstall job gets to the point where the batch file is executed, at which point a cmd window will appear and run.  Any ideas of how to run this script without displaying extra windows?

The script is ran with `-windowstyle hidden` as well.

Comment: Might be a dirty solution but, provided you have the necessary permissions, you could create an "uninstall" user and start your job using the corresponding credentials. The command prompt will only show for the user currently logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be indulgent, I'am not proud of this, but I'am quite sure that if you try to localy run your script using remoting the window will not be seen by the user :

I just try :

```
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName localhost
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {calc.exe}
get-process "calc"
```

In your case try :

```
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName localhost
$job = Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Product |? {$_Name -eq "Annoying1"}).uninstall()} -asjob -Name Uninstall1
wait-job $job
receive-job $job
```

Comment: Yes, this is an excellent idea and would do the trick but unfortunately the WinRM service that `New-PSSession` requires isn't enabled for our approved configuration.